# How to access 2D arrays in a list of lists of arrays and convert them to a 3D array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I read dataset of images and make a list of lists of the arrays:

```
img_all = [[img00, img01, ..., img0n], [img10, img11, ..., img1n], ..., [imgm0, imgm1, ..., imgmn]]
```

From this list, I want to get median images of (img00, img10, ..., imgm0), (img01, img11, ..., imgm1), ..., (img0n, img1n, ..., imgmn).

I can access imgij with img_all[i][j] but, how can I access all arrays over i and convert them to a 3D array so I can get their median image by np.median()? np.array(img_all[:][j]) does not return what I want.

Note that imgij is a numpy 2D array and the shape of the images are the same over i at j, i.e.,

img00, img10,...imgm0 are the same shape.

img01, img11,...imgm1 are the same shape.

...,

img0n, img1n,...imgmn are the same shape.

Below is a code in which I read images and want to get the median images, but it does not work because I cannot access the arrays in the list of lists of arrays as I want. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import numpy as np

def get_image(channel):
    if channel == 0:
        dim0 = 8    
    if channel == 1:
        dim0 = 140
    if channel == 2:
        dim0 = 38
    if channel == 3:
        dim0 = 159        
    return np.random.rand(dim0, 10)

# Read data and make a list of lists of arrays
ndays = range(5)
channels = [0, 1, 2, 3]
img_all = []
for iday in ndays:
    img_channel = []
    for jth_channel in channels:
        img = get_image(jth_channel)
        img_channel.append(img)
    img_all.append(img_channel)

# Get median arrays
medians = []
for j in channels:
    imgs_channel_j = np.array(img_all[:][j]) ### I want to make an array of images for jth channel
    print(imgs_channel_j.shape) # Here I thought I would get an array with the shape of (4, 8, 10) at j=0, (4, 140, 10) at j=1, .... but not.
    img_median = np.median(imgs_channel_j, axis=0)
    medians.append(img_median)
```

Comment: Ones that match in shape can be joined with `np.stack`.

Comment: ```np.stack(img_all[:][j])``` does not work either because img_all[:][j] does not return the list of 2d arrays that match the shape. It seems img_all[:][j] does not care the slice and returns what img_all[j] returns..

Comment: `arr[:]` does nothing. `arr[:, 0]` gives the first column.  It pays to read the basic numpy docs.

Comment: I know how to access elements in an array, but as I explain in the original question img_all is not an array but a list. In this list there are a number of lists that are composed of different shape of 2d arrays.